# Transition probabilities for Gibbs Sampling in a Markov Random Field

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am currently reading this paper (http://image.diku.dk/igel/paper/AItRBM-proof.pdf) on Restricted Boltzmann Machines.

On page 22,

Given a Markov Random Field $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ w.r.t a graph $G = (V,E)$ where $V = \{1 \ldots N\}$ and $i \in V$. The Gibbs sampling procedure is as follows:

At each transition step, pick random variable $X_i$, with a probability $q(i)$ given by strictly positive probability distribution $q$ on $V$.

Then, sample a new value of $X_i$ based on it's conditional probability distribution given the state $(x_v)_{v \in V \setminus i}$ of all other variables $(X_v)_{v \in V \setminus i}$ i.e. based on $\pi(X_i \vert (x_v)_{v \in V \setminus i})$.

Given the above steps, the paper states the transition probabilities $p_{xy}$ for two states $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ of the MRF $\mathbf{X}$ to be: [Link to equations for $p_{xx}, p_{xy}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXFtW.png)

I don't quite understand:
1) should $p_{xx}$ term have a product over all $i \in V$ as opposed to the sum?
2) why $p_{xy}$ does not have a sum over all $i \in V$.